# How to disable graphical console after kernel boot?

Tags: linux, kernel

I have a Linux kernel booting up.  It comes up in native screen size graphical framebuffer mode due to use of kernel mode setting.  During the kernel boot, the screen shifts from text to graphical console mode and lots of kernel messages get dumped.  Once control is handed to the first userland program, I'd like that program to be able to disable the graphical console output.  How do I do that?

Comment: Can you please define `disabling the graphical console output'?

Comment: Preventing the graphical console from outputting to the framebuffer.  I am looking for some programmable setting that will allow me to disconnect the graphical console from outputting to the frame buffer.  This so my userland program can have exclusive output to the framebuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `vga=0` to the kernel options to force text mode.

Comment: As a kernel boot parameter correct?  Is this different than using the quiet parameter?  I want the screen to stay in graphical mode, I just don't want the boot time graphical console to be able to output to the framebuffer.

Comment: BTW, this doesnt force text mode in my situation.  I also have i915.modeset=1 on the kernel parameter line and it appears to trump vga=0

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood what you're trying to achieve. But then, I'm confused - why? Can you write what is the actual issue? Maybe there is a better solution?